# Obtaining meaningful JSON from R

Tags: javascript, json, r, rest

I am working on some simple processing in R. The goal is to pull tickets (incidents) from a ticketing system (for these purposes I am pulling only the incident numbers and the creation date). I am pulling via REST that returns an JSON object. I'm utilizing the HTTR package to do so. I do this as such:

```
URL <= "http://......"
incidentsQuery <- GET(URL, username=..., password=...., ..., accept_json())
```

Now, I have the return, but my goal is to get some counts by month and year. So I convert this to a data frame using:

```
incidentsJSON <- content(incidentQuery, type="text")
incidentsDF <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(incidentsJSON)
```

Now I have the information into a data frame so I can use as.yearmon from the Zoo package to obtain the month and year, then aggregate the count (length) against the year and month. So, now I have return that gives me something like this:

```
MonthYear  Count
Nov 2014   909
Dec 2014   4354
Jan 2015   4484
....
```

Now, with my knowledge of R, I store this into a data frame. Then I want to convert it back to a meaningful JSON format so I can use D3.js to do some web graphics. Based on the standard format for JSON, it should follow a format like:

```
{
 "result":
  {
     "MonthYear": "Nov 2014",
     "Count": 909
  },
  {
     "MonthYear": "Dec 2015",
     "Count": 4354
  }
}
```

Instead (and I am using the jsonlite package by the way), I use:

```
incidentCountJSON <- toJSON(incidentDFCounts, pretty=TRUE)
```

Then I write that to a file using write(). Opening the file, I get:

```
[
  {
     "MonthYear": "Nov 2014",
     "Count": 909
  },
  {
     "MonthYear": "Dec 2015",
     "Count": 4354
  }
]
```

I am sort of a newbie at JSON, just learning this, but I know this returns an array of objects, which I am having a hard time parsing for the D3.js and Chart.js libraries/frameworks. I want to make sure I am following a JSON standard and able to process the data into R and back out into a standard format. Can someone give me some suggestions/hints on how to do this, or where I am going wrong? Thank you so much, in advance. I apologize for anything I might have missed, but I am a first time poster. Please let me know if there is more information needed.

Comment: Your output is valid JSON. See [this validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) in case you want to check. JSON data can be represented in two ways. Either column-wise (a named array of vectors) or row-wise (a vector of named arrays). Your output is the last part. I have some ramblings in JSON in R in case you want to read some more

Comment: Ekstroem -  Thanks for your response. If I wanted it in the other format (starting and ending with { }, rather than [ ], how would I do such a thing? I assume this is what you are calling a named array of vecotors... My goal is in my JavaScript side to easily take the MonthYear and assign it to an array (or vector) like: var monthyear: ["Jan 2015", "Feb 2015"] and the same with the counts... that way I can pass those to a Chart.js chart. Sorry, this may end up to be more of a JS question...

Comment: The `toJSON` function in the `jsonlite` package seems to dump data in the vector of named arrays format, but the `toJSON` function in the `rjson` package seems to write in the other format. Can you use that?

Comment: Let me check this out and I'll post my results. I wasn't aware they handled these differently. I have used both packages, but didn't know they provided different outputs. I will try tonight and post and update tomorrow. Thanks!!

Comment: I think you are looking for the `dataframe` argument. As an example, `jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars,dataframe="columns")`.

Comment: So, I figured out how to get the JSON into R - I was using the JSONLITE package, and ended up using RSONIO package - that worked better, not even sure why, but I guess the examples I looked at used that package, so maybe it has something to do with how each package handles the JSON. I'm new to the JSON arena, so I'm still learning. I have another question on this, though. Now that I can get the JSON into R - I'm dealing with another issue and that's parsing nested JSON. Any tips or resources on how I can do this effectively? I am using HTTR to read it in, then I use content() to grab the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information above that Lars posted guided me to the solution. I am posting this as a confirmed answer to the issue I had. I wasn't able to accept the comments as an answer (that I know of), so I am posting this as the answer to the question.